# DrawRect with clear background and custom gradient layer

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uikit

In `UIView` if you do the following:

```
CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
layer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id) [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0.1 alpha:1].CGColor,[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.74 alpha:1].CGColor, nil];
layer.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height);
[self.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
```

Will `drawRect` then perform custom drawing on top of this gradient? Does `drawRect` affect the actual background of a view, or is it a different layer entirely? If the background color of the view is `clearColor` does `drawRect` still display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sublayer obscures the content of its superlayer.  If you override `drawRect:` to draw content, that content will be obscured by the gradient layer.

If you want to draw the gradient behind your (view) content, you should either draw the gradient in your `drawRect:` instead of using a sublayer, or use a container view that contains both the gradient layer and your `drawRect:`-using content view, with your content view on top.

Also, if you want the gradient layer to cover your view, it would be better to initialize `layer.frame` like this:

```
layer.frame = self.bounds;
```